# LVM: Auto-activate VG on removable HDD reconnection

Tags: linux, lvm

I have a external HDD with LVM partitions.

In order to prevent kernel device errors, it turns out I need to 
[deactivate my VG before removal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18042216/5353461).

Is there a way of having the VG appear automatically when the drive is reconnected?

Or a work-around to prevent the kernel `dm-X` device errors?

Comment: pv/vgscan with a udev rule?

Comment: @RamanSailopal scanning finds VGs but doesn't activate them.

Comment: vgchange -a y will activate all known volume groups in the system

Comment: @RamanSailopal `vgchange -ay` does the trick. If you make an answer with a `udev` rule example I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Raman Sailopal's suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391798/lvm-auto-activate-vg-on-removable-hdd-reconnection#comment698428_391798) I added the following `udev` rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-disk.rules`:

```
# Trigger LVM auto-activate
ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", ENV{ID_WWN}=="0x50004cf2105f4f7b", RUN+="/usr/bin/vgchange -a ay 2TB"
```

1. Get `ID_WWN` from `udevadm info -a --query=property --name /dev/<DEVICE> | grep WWN`
2. Replace `2TB` with the VG you wish to auto-activate
3. `sudo udevadm control --reload` to load the changes